# OpenLayers: get pixel color from image layer

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a simple map with a static pixel image layer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    // reference to jquery here
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>

      var extent = [0, 0, 2000000, 2000000];
      var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'xkcd-image',
        units: 'pixels',
        extent: extent
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });

      image = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
          url: 'http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/online_communities.png',
          projection: projection,
          imageExtent: extent
        })
      });

      map.addLayer(image);

      image.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        var xy = evt.pixel;
        console.log(xy);
        var canvasContext = $('.ol-unselectable')[0].getContext('2d');
        var pixelAtClick = canvasContext.getImageData(xy[0], xy[1], 1, 1).data;
        var red = pixelAtClick[0]; // green is [1] , blue is [2] , alpha is [4]
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When clicking on the image I want to get the color of the pixel that I clicked on. As far as I understand the raster source example (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/examples/raster.html), this is only possible with raster sources so I converted the image into a raster source. (When I add that raster source to the layer, I get the message that this operation is insecure, so I still use the image to show on the map.)

Here ([How to get a pixel's color value from an Openlayers 3 layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873958/how-to-get-a-pixels-color-value-from-an-openlayers-3-layer)) the color is read from evt.context. However, with me evt.context is undefined.

Addendum: There might be several image layers overlaying each other. I need to get the color from a single specific image layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this isn't ideal but might send you along the right lines:

You can use the pixel xy of the click event to query the canvas object that openlayers creates and puts your map data onto.

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {    
    var xy = evt.pixel;
    var canvasContext = $('.ol-unselectable')[0].getContext('2d');   
    var pixelAtClick = canvasContext.getImageData(xy[0], xy[1], 1, 1).data;
    var red = pixeAtClick[0]; // green is [1] , blue is [2] , alpha is [4]
  });
```

This assumes that you are using jQuery and that the canvas is the first DOM element using the class '.ol-unselectable'.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That works, but I need a slightly different result: I need only the color from the image (e.g. in case the image layer is transparent, the color of the image with full opacity should be returned).

I edited my code in the opening post according to your suggestions, with the .on function for the layer. However, the function does not seem to be called.

Comment: By the way, using the .on function with the map raises an "operation is insecure" error as soon as the image is shown within the view (probably because of the same origin policy). However, showing the image works.

Comment: Minor comment, but alpha would be position [3] in the array not [4]

Comment: As a workaround, the following works well for me: Check if the pixel that was clicked on lies within the extent of the layer. If so, change the opacity of the layer to 1, raise the layer to the front (using its z-index), apply DFox's solution, set the opacity and the z-index back to their original values.

However, the same-origin policy must be fulfilled for doing so, e.g. by accessing all files from the same server.