# Openlayers 4: Getting Pixeldata from Map appears to have an offset

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have written a function to retrieve pixel data from an openlayers map:

```js
var imagery = new ol.layer.Tile({
 source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});

var context;

/**
 * Apply a filter on "postcompose" events.
 */
imagery.on('postcompose', function(event) {
 context = event.context;
});

function getPixel( latitude, longitude ){
    let lat = parseFloat( latitude );
    let lon = parseFloat( longitude );
    var coord = ol.proj.transform( [lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857' );
    var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate( coord );
    if( context == null )
     return;
    return  context.getImageData(pixel[0], pixel[1], 1, 1).data;
}

var map = new ol.Map({
 target: 'map',
 layers: [imagery],
    ...
});
```

The code is based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35081751/openlayers-get-pixel-color-from-image-layer). Also, the transformation from LatLon data to pixel coordinates is used quite extensively and does not provide any problems.

However, the pixel data that is retrieved is somehow offset from the coordinates, so that I see water where there is land and otherwise. As far as I can tell, the offset is a few hundred pixels (or a few meters in lonlat) in x and y direction, and probably the cause lies in the fact that the pixels from the map do not correspond to that of the canvas.

Does anyone have a clue on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: You may need to include pixelRatio in the offsets, as in the code used here https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/layer-spy.html

Comment: Thanks Mike. That indeed solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Mike's response indeed put me on the right track!
I have included the modified code for those who may run into the same issue:

```js
var pixelRatio;
var context;

var imagery = new ol.layer.Tile({
 source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});

/**
 * before rendering the layer, determine the pixel ratio
 * and save the context
*/
imagery.on('precompose', function(event) {
  context = event.context;
  pixelRatio = event.frameState.pixelRatio;
  context.save();
});

/**
 * Restore the context
 */
imagery.on('postcompose', function(event) {
 context = event.context;
 context.restore();
});

/**
 * Get the pixel's rgba data
 */
function getPixel( latitude, longitude, offx, offy ){
 let lat = parseFloat( latitude );
 let lon = parseFloat( longitude );
 var coord = ol.proj.transform( [lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857' );
 var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate( coord );
 if( context == null )
  return;
 var pixelAtClick = context.getImageData(pixel[0]*pixelRatio, pixel[1]*pixelRatio, 1, 1).data;
 rgb = [0,0,0,0];
 for( var i=0;i<pixelAtClick.length;i++ ){
  rgb[i] = pixelAtClick[i];
 }
 return rgb;
}
```